# Using Spring & Eureka Client in a separate project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a project (projectA) that uses Spring-cloud Eureka and Ribbon:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ClassA extends AbstractClassA
```

I use it in another project (I have projectA as a maven dependency) which is a spring boot project and it works perfectly, Eureka and all. All Dependencies are injected normally. But I have some other projects that use ProjectA but don't use spring boot, just typical spring-mvc/web and I get the following error, even when I don't explicitly use ClassA, occurring at runtime:

```
WARN Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling  refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [projectA.impl.ClassA]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient found, but there are no implementations.  Did you forget to include a starter?
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:437)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at projectB.App.main(App.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient found, but there are no implementations.Did you forget to include a starter?
    at org.springframework.cloud.util.SpringFactoryImportSelector.selectImports(SpringFactoryImportSelector.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:429)
    ... 10 more
```

These are some of the dependencies in the project that failed, no parent:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Angel.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>ribbon-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>ribbon-loadbalancer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    .....
```

Any advice on what could be the issue? I looked into @EnabkeEurekaClient on github and it requires I have Eureka on the classpath, which I should given the above pom.

Comment: You shouldn't need `eureka-client`, `ribbon-eureka`, `ribbon-loadbalancer`, `ribbon`, `spring-cloud-netflix-core` and `spring-cloud-commons`. You should just use `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` and `spring-cloud-starter-ribbon`. According to those dependencies you shouldn't get that error, but obviously something else is going on. What does `mvn dependency:tree` show.

Comment: I didn't have those originally and it still did not work. I removed them again and I don't see anything particular weird with the dependency tree. It contains 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.1.147:compile' and 'com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.0.0:compile' under the eureka starter

Comment: Then I'll need a sample project to determine why.

Comment: May I email you at the email you put on your github?

Comment: Yes you may send it.